# Já que, antigamente, se escrevia "acertal-o", por que não continou assim?

Tags: ortografia

Já vi, em alguns textos mais antigos, se escrever (1) "tratal-o" ao invés de "tratá-lo". Escrever-se "tratal-o" tem mais sentido, já que é como se o R tivesse "se transformado" em L — algo que não é incomum, em línguas. Não estou falando do acento.

Tendo isso em vista, por que foi mudada a grafia de "l-o" para "-lo"?

(1) http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/lim/LIM3270.htm

> § 13. Todos os libertos maiores de 60 annos, preenchido o tempo de serviço de que trata o § 10, continuarão em companhia de seus ex-senhores, que serão obrigados a **alimental-os**, **vestil-os**, e **tratal-os** em suas molestias, usufruindo os serviços compativeis com as forças delles, salvo si preferirem obter em outra parte os meios de subsistencia, e os Juizes de Orphãos os julgarem capazes de o fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grafia *acertá-lo* faz sentido porque os nossos pronomes *o, a* eram antigamente *lo, la*. Eis o que diz a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 358):

> 1.ª As formas antigas do pronome oblíquo objeto direto eram *lo(s)* e *la(s)*, provenientes do acusativo do demonstrativo latino *ille, illa, illud* (= aquele, aquela, aquilo). Pospostas a formas verbais terminadas em   *-r, -s* ou *-z*, o seu *l-* inicial assimilou aquelas consoantes, que depois desapareceram:
>
> faze**r-lo** > faze**l-lo** > fazê-**lo**
>         faze**s-lo** > faze**l-lo** > faze-**lo**
>         fi**z-lo** > fi**l-lo** > fi-**lo**

A assimilação mencionada acima refere-se ao primeiro passo: o *l-* assimilar o *-r, -s* e *-z* significa torná-los semelhantes a si. Manuel Said Ali ([*Gramática Histórica da Língua Portuguesa*, 1931, p. 36-35](https://archive.org/stream/M.saidAli.grammaticaHistoricaDaLinguaPorugueza/GrammaticaHistoricaDaLinguaPortugueza#page/n53/mode/2up/search/ficavam+subordinados)) dá a mesma explicação.

Agora, até ao século XVI, a tua questão não se punha, porque, explica Said Ali, o pronome enclítico se escrevia pegado ao verbo, sem hífen. Diz ele que o Padre António Vieira (1608-1697) ainda escrevia assim. Depois passou a escrever-se *fazel-o, fil-o*, etc., e as reformas ortográficas de 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil é que oficializaram a grafia atual (isto explico eu, que o próprio Said Ali ainda escrevia com o *l* antes do hífen).

Não encontrei ninguém que justificasse diretamente a mudança da posição do hífen. Para mim faz sentido, porque podemos conceber o *lo, la* como as formas antigas dos pronomes: o *-r, -s* e *-z* não passariam a *-l* se não estivesse lá originalmente o *l-* do *lo, la*. O [Formulário Ortográfico de 1911](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1911) (XXXIV — outro empregos do hífen) vai ao ponto de dizer que:

> São erros inadmissíveis, mas muito frequentes, *louval-o, devel-o, punil-o*, etc.

Não justificam esta posição, que me parece extremista e absurda. Eu acho *acertá-lo* mais razoável que *acertal-o*, mas em 1911, *acertal-o* era a convenção geral. Eu tenho lido edições antigas de livros do Machado de Assis, Eça de Queiroz, Alexandre Herculano e outros clássicos, e todos eles escreviam *fazel-o, fil-o*; o Fernando Pessoa ignorou a nova ortografia oficial e continuou a escrever na antiga. Não se pode acusar uma pessoa de cometer um erro inadmissível por ignorar uma norma ortográfica acabada de ser instituída e continuar a escrever como aprendeu.

Comment: Eu achava que era "fazer-o" -> "fazê-lo". Mas assim tem mais sentido, realmente.

Comment: @Schilive, eu não sei se alguma vez tinha pensado alguma coisa. A exposição na *Gramática Histórica* (link na resposta) é muito interessante. Dá exemplos antigos, *fosteslo* (foste-lo), *creerlos* (crê-los), e coisas que já não se usam, como *todolos*, formado pelo mesmo processo de *todos* + *los*.